# Adding variable to prop

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to React, and I'm sorry beforehand if I use the wrong terms for certain pieces!

I have imported some images in the top if my file with `import face_1 from "./assets/face-1.png";` (where the numbers increase up to 6, since I'm making dice)

Later on, I want to show those images based on the value of the die, so I want to grab the images as follows: `<img className="dice-image" src={face_#} alt={roll} />;`. I want # to be the same value as `{roll}`, but I can't figure out how I can add the value of `{roll}` to `src`?

So basically, I want the `<img>`-tag to look like this:
`<img className="dice-image" src={face_{roll}} alt={roll} />`

Is this at all possible? Or do I have to create the `face_3` just before I call it as a prop?

Comment: You'll save yourself a lot of headaches if you just put all the images into an array and use them from there.

Comment: I'm working from a tutorial (which I finished), and I'm now trying to make the code better (since the tutorial wanted me to pull the images out like this: https://i.imgur.com/jDDDqHb.png), but I hadn't thought about putting the images in an array AT ALL, since I wanted to fix the way the images were returned. Thanks for the idea! :D

Answer (score 0):

Putting all the values into an array, as suggested by Guy Incognito, is a straightforward way to handle this:

```js
const faces = [face_1, face_2, face_3, face_4, face_5, face_6];
return (
  <>
    {faces.map((face, i) => (
      <img className="dice-iamge" key={i} src={face} alt={roll} />
    ))}
  </>
);
```